# WPF Dynamic Data Display Not Showing Line Plot

Tags: c#, wpf, plot

I've written a simple application and I want to plot some of the data it calculates. I've come across `Dynamic Data Display` on Google and it looks like exactly the kind of thing I need, except I can't get the plot to appear.

I have the following XAML:

```
<Window ... xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0" ..>

<d3:ChartPlotter Name="plotter" Background="Cornsilk" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
        <d3:Header>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20">Very simple chart</TextBlock>
        </d3:Header>
        <d3:HorizontalAxisTitle>This is horizontal axis</d3:HorizontalAxisTitle>
        <d3:VerticalAxisTitle>This is vertical axis</d3:VerticalAxisTitle>
        <d3:Footer>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" FontStyle="Italic">
                Footer example
            </TextBlock>
        </d3:Footer>
</d3:ChartPlotter>
```

And this C# linked up to a button's `onClick` event:

```
        int[] xarr = { 2, 4, 6 };
        int[] yarr = { 1, 1, 1 };
        EnumerableDataSource<int> x = new EnumerableDataSource<int>(xarr);
        EnumerableDataSource<int> y = new EnumerableDataSource<int>(yarr);
        CompositeDataSource toplot = new CompositeDataSource(x, y);
        plotter.AddLineGraph(toplot);
```

When I click the button an annotation appears in the top right of the plot saying `LineGraph`, but no line is visible. I'd appreciate any help getting this working.

Update:

I've noticed the following error message in the Debug Console:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')
```

Comment: That's kinda hard to help since it's just some 3'rd party library and not part of the WPF framework , they have some samples there to download , why don't you copy paste the LineGraph sample and build on top of that

Comment: I appreciate that it's tricky, I was just hoping perhaps someone had some experience with that library, it has a high Google ranking and I'm sure plotting data is a common task. I'll take your comment on board and try working back from an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use ObservableDataSource instead of CompositeDataSource. As soon as you add values the DataChanged event is raised and the graph should update itself.

I am not quit sure, if you have to add a Horizontal/Vertical Axis to your XAML.